# Coluna condicional baseada em varias linhas dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho esse df:

```
structure(list(id = c("R054", "R054", "R054", "R054", "R054", 
"GT68U", "GT68U", "GT68U", "GT68U", "GT68U", "G001", "G001", 
"G001", "G001"), car1 = c("sim", "sim", "sim", "sim", "sim", 
"sim", "nao", "sim", "nao", "nao", "nao", "nao", "nao", "nao"
)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Gostaria de criar uma nova coluna baseada nos valores de car1 para o conjunto de linhas de cada id.
Caso o id sempre tenha car1 "sim" ou "nao" a nova coluna  apenas replica a informação. Caso o id tenha "sim" ou "nao" a nova coluna deve apresentar "nd". De forma que ficasse assim:

```
id      car1    output
R054    sim     sim
R054    sim     sim
R054    sim     sim
R054    sim     sim
R054    sim     sim
GT68U   sim     nd
GT68U   nao     nd
GT68U   sim     nd
GT68U   nao     nd
GT68U   nao     nd
G001    nao     nao
G001    nao     nao
G001    nao     nao
G001    nao     nao
```

Tentei usar a função mutate

```
df %>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  mutate(output = case_when(car1 == "nao" & car1 == "nao" ~ "nao",
                            car1 == "sim" & car1 == "sim" ~ "sim",
                            car1 == "sim" & car1 == "nao" ~ "nd",
                        TRUE ~ 0))
```

mas recebo o erro

Error: must be a character vector, not a double vector
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 7):

Utilizei o `group_by` + `mutate` + `case_when` + `all` para verificar se todas as ocorrências do id determinado era de sim/não e os que fossem mistos seriam valores faltantes e preenchidos com nd.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id)%>%
  mutate(output = case_when(
    all(car1 == 'sim')  ~ 'sim',
    all(car1 == 'nao') ~ 'nao',
    TRUE ~ 'nd'
  ))
```

Saída:

```
   id    car1  output
   <chr> <chr> <chr> 
 1 R054  sim   sim   
 2 R054  sim   sim   
 3 R054  sim   sim   
 4 R054  sim   sim   
 5 R054  sim   sim   
 6 GT68U sim   nd    
 7 GT68U nao   nd    
 8 GT68U sim   nd    
 9 GT68U nao   nd    
10 GT68U nao   nd    
11 G001  nao   nao   
12 G001  nao   nao   
13 G001  nao   nao   
14 G001  nao   nao
```

Answer (score 2):

[@lmonferrari já respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/479006/117168) como usar o `dplyr::case_when` no seu caso; esta é outra opção, usando `ifelse` e `unique`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(output = ifelse(length(unique(car1)) == 1, car1, "nd"))
```

Se no grupo houver só um valor para `car1` (seja qual for), `unique` terá comprimento 1; nesse caso, `output` é preenchido com o valor correspondente de `car1`, caso contrário, com "nd".

Para ficar registrado, eis o equivalente com *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, output := ifelse(length(unique(car1)) == 1, car1, "nd"), id]
# ou, usando data.table::fifelse, bem mais rápido:
df[, output := fifelse(length(unique(car1)) == 1, unique(car1)[1], "nd"), id]
```

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de a pergunta pedir uma solução `dplyr`, aqui fica uma solução R base, em uma linha, com a função `ave`.

```
df$output <- ave(df$car1, df$id, FUN = function(x) if(all(x == x[1])) x else "nd")
```